# Efficiently removing projection to subspace without having an orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I have a number of vectors $v_1, …, v_n$ and another vector $w$, that all are linearly independent, but not orthogonal. Let $V := \mathop{\text{span}}(v_1, …, v_n)$. I need to remove $w$’s projection to $V$ from $w$, i.e., I need to find the vector $\tilde{w}$ such that $\langle \tilde{w},v \rangle = 0 ~∀~ v∈ V$ and $w-\tilde{w} ∈ V$. I need to do this exactly once for a given $V$.

Note that the scalar product is not the canonical scalar product and has a higher cost than $n$. Touching the scalar product would be extremely tedious, so for the purpose of this question you can consider it a blackbox.

My best solution for this so far is to apply Gram–Schmidt orthonormalisation to the collection $v_1, …, v_n, w$, without normalising the last vector, which then is $\tilde{w}$. With other words, I first orthonormalise $v_1, …, v_n$ to $\hat{v}_1, …, \hat{v}_n$ and then separately remove $w$’s projections to $\hat{v}_1, …, \hat{v}_n$ to obtain $\tilde{w}$.

Doing this, I need to calculate $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ scalar products (or norms) just to orthonormalise $V$ as a prerequisite for the last step, which only involves $n$ scalar products. This feels like there could be some more efficient way to do this, but I cannot find one.

Comment: Isn't this just the QR decomposition of $V$? The two other common methods are with Householder reflections and Givens rotations, but in any case you'd probably want to use a standard library implementation of QR. Also, the QR takes $O(n^3)$ time, but the projection takes $O(n^2)$ time, which should make it negligible.

Comment: Related post on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145688/how-to-project-a-vector-onto-a-very-large-non-orthogonal-subspace

Comment: @Kirill: Yes, orthonormalising $V$ is somewhat equivalent to the $QR$ decomposition. And it’s exactly what I do not need – I only want to project a single vector ($w$). Also, if my scalar product had a cost of $\mathcal{O}(n)$, my $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ vs. $n$ would turn into your  $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ vs  $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$

Comment: @ChristianClason: Thank you. However my problem is not of so large a scale and approximate solutions are not an alternative for me.

Comment: How is this different from solving a general least-squares problem of minimizing $\|Vx-w\|^2$? I don't think that can be done in $O(n^2)$ time, which seems to be what you're asking for.

Comment: @Kirill: The scalar product is not the canonical one, though this of course is “only” a change of basis. If you can argue that the problems are sufficiently equivalent, and other, potentially faster (but still $\mathcal{O}{n^3}$) methods of solving this problem ($QR$ decomposition) do not translate well to arbitrary scalar products, this may very well be an answer to my question.

Comment: Without knowing *how* the scalar product differs (is it only $x^TAy$ instead of $x^Ty$ for some spd matrix $A$, or something more involved?), it's hard to help you here...

Comment: @ChristianClason: It’s a complicated function-based scalar product based on a piecewise Hermite interpolation of a set of unevenly spaced anchor points. Of course, I can write down some spd matrix for it (you can do this for every scalar product on a finite space, IIRC), but  that’s already rather tedious. Due to this and some other reasons that need a lot of explanation, you can assume the scalar product to be a blackbox.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your question boils down to "Can I save some effort in (modified) Gram--Schmidt if I use the orthogonalized basis vectors immediately for a projection and don't intend to keep them?" (My guess is no, not in the sense that you can reduce $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^s)$ for $s<3$, but you might be able to lower the constant -- unless there's some special structure in the scalar product and/or the vectors $v$ that you can exploit.)

Comment: @ChristianClason: Yes.

Comment: While it's unlikely that there is anything like what you are asking for, it might make sense to ask on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ if there are known impossibility results or known complexity lower bounds. Maybe this isn't relevant, but I want to add that I don't fully understand your comment about the scalar product being a blackbox: to get its matrix you don't have to do anything (tedious) by hand, to extract matrix coefficients you just evaluate (numerically, in code, presumably only once) all the inner products $(e_i, Be_j)$, no manual work is necessary.

Comment: @Kirill: *you just evaluate (numerically, in code, presumably only once) all the inner products $(e_i,Be_j)$, no manual work is necessary.* – Yes, and that would be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ scalar products. Also, note that I need to orthogonalise only once for every $V$ (otherwise, I wouldn’t be so bothered about orthogonalising $V$ either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Converted to an answer from my comments to Jan's answer.*

To fix dimensions and notation, let us say that $V$ is a $m\times n$ matrix with the vectors $v_i$ as columns.

As Jan notes, we have to compute
$$
\tilde w = [I - V(V^TMV)^{-1}V^TM]w,
$$
where $M$ is the symmetric $m\times m$ matrix associated to the scalar product.

If it were possible to solve this problem with $O(n)$ black-box calls to the scalar product $M$, like the OP asks, then it would mean that we can solve the version of the problem in which $M=I$ in $O(mn)$, since now each scalar product costs $O(m)$. This seems too much to ask for, since the usual algorithms to compute projections (QR, SVD, solving the normal equations $(V^TV)^{-1}V^Tw$ explicitly...) all cost $O(mn^2)$.

*This answer is an amended and corrected version of the comments: in the comments I claim that computing the scalar product costs $O(m)$ for each matrix $M$, but on second thought this is not true in general. For $M=I$ it's fine, though.*

Answer (score 4):

What about simply computing the projection of $w$ along the complement of $V$?
$$
\tilde w = [I - V(VV^T)^{-1}V^T]w,
$$
where $V$ is the matrix that has the basis vectors of $V$ as columns. This $\tilde w$ has all the properties that you look for.

If you are in the non standard scalar product, then there is a symmetric positive matrix $M$ that induces this scalar product. In this case the projection reads
$$
\tilde w = [I - V(V^TMV)^{-1}V^TM]w.
$$

It is OK, if the scalar product is a black box. You only need it's realization.

EDIT: The costs are mainly in the solve with $(V^TMV)$. If CG is applied, there will be a number of scalar product evaluations needed that scales with $n^2$: $\mathcal O(n)$ evaluations times $\mathcal O(n)$ iterations. (read the comments)

Comment: Can you elaborate of the computational complexity of this method? I have the feeling that it would be much worse, given that I have to solve a linear equation system and such.

Comment: Depends on how you will do the solve with $(V^TMV)$. In any case it will be less than the orthogonalization of $V$ with respect to $M$. Since $(V^TMV)$ is symmetric positive definite, you can apply CG. With CG, the cost of the overall procedure (and the number of evaluations of the scalar product) scales linearly with $n$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, wouldn’t I already need $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ evaluations of the scalar product to determine $M$?

Comment: Not necessarily... you will need the application of $M$ to a vector.

Comment: Your formula is formally identical to a singular value decomposition and project on the singular vectors (which are an orthonormal set of vectors for the given subspace). Performing the SVD (which is often done via the QR algorithm) is usually numerically more stable than inverting $V^TV$. And the (order of) complexity is for both the same as for Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Are you sure that the number of scalar products scales linearly with $n$ if one uses CG? It seems to me that a linear number of scalar products is required to compute $(V^TMV)x$ for a vector $x$, simply because the output has $n$ entries. So the total number of evaluations is still quadratic.

Comment: @davidhigh You are missing the part about the nonstandard scalar product. Unless you know how to do an SVD with respect to that standard product (and it's not clear to me how), this is a more complicated problem.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I see... You are right. Complexity will be quadratic then.

Comment: @FredericoPoloni: you're right I haven't considered the non-standard scalar product -- or rather, I was assuming there will exist an SVD adapted to non-standard scalar products. The term $V^T(V^T V)^{-1}$ just reminded me of least squares solving, and there the credo is: always use the SVD and not the normal equation.

Comment: The statement in your edit about the order when using CG is not correct imo. Solving (general spd) linear systems is O(n^3), regardless of the method. And for dense systems, there are better ways of solving than CG.

Comment: @davidhigh The cost is $O(n^2)$ scalar products; each scalar product costs $O(m)$ floating point operations, where $m \geq n$ is the length of the involved vectors (which, surprisingly, no one has mentioned expilcitly yet). So the overall cost is $O(mn^2)$ flops, which is exactly what we expect from an algorithm for this kind of problems (such as a thin QR or SVD of a $m\times n$ matrix). This is also why I consider unlikely that there is a solution with $O(n)$ scalar products, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: exactly. And then, as we are at $O(mn^2)$ anyways, for the non-standard scalar product one can also do a Cholesky decomposition $M=L^TL$ ($O(n^3)$ where $n\leq m$), and afterwards a SVD of $LV$ ... that's still $O(mn^2)$ together.

Comment: @davidhigh The problem is that in this setting you cannot access the entries of $M$ directly. You just have a black-box function that computes $x^*My$ for any two given vectors $x,y$, and you want to compute the projection with the minimum number of calls. The OP's original solution uses $O(n^2)$ calls, as well as Jan's one, and the OP hopes that one can find a method in $O(n)$ calls only. I doubt it's possible, because it would mean that there is a method to solve the version of the problem in which $M$ is given explicitly in $O(mn)$ flops, which beats the linear algebra in common use.

Comment: @davidhigh Oh, and another correction: $M$ is $m\times m$, not $n\times n$, so Choleskying it costs $O(m^3)$, which is way too much.

Comment: @federicopoloni maybe you can summarize your comments in an answer which then can be discussed or accepted.

Comment: @Jan Done. (character limit)